# A combinatorics problem that seems faulty

Tags: combinatorics

I've come across the following problem.

> Show that the number of elements of $X$ belonging to a least $r$ of the sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n\subset X$ is $$\sum_{k=r}^n(-1)^{k-r}{k-1\choose r-1}S_k^{(n)}.$$

It's a problem from a homework set given in a class I don't attend. (Not my university even.) So I don't have any way of asking anyone anything about it. And it seems to me that the problem doesn't make any sense. Nothing is said about $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ in the problem other than they are subsets of $X$ so the only way I can interpret this is that the number in question should be independent of the choice $A_1,\ldots, A_n$. But I think it's absolutely not independent. If $A_1=\ldots=A_n=\varnothing$, then clearly the number in question is $0$, whatever the $r$ is. But if $n=1$, $A_1=X=\{\text{Tom Hanks}\},$ and $r=1$ then the number in question is $1$.

It doesn't help that I don't know what $S_k^{(n)}$ means, but whatever it is, it seems that either I completely misunderstand the problem or it is faulty.

Could you please explain the problem to me, and, if it's not too much trouble, help me solve it?

Comment: Email the teacher and ask. $S_k^{(n)}$ probably depends on the sets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$.

Comment: @Samuel I can't email the teacher. I don't even know who it is.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to use the Principle of Inclusion of Exclusion. That will give you a hint about what $S^{(n)}_k$ represents.

Comment: @Calvin Thank you. I see that inclusion-exclusion should be relevant, but I still can't get my head around it. The number in question is the cardinality of $$\bigcup_{1\leq i_1\leq\ldots\leq i_r\leq n}A_{i_1}\cap\ldots\cap A_{i_r},$$ right? But how can I even think I could compute that not knowing what the subsets are or what the cardinality of $X$ is?